# How to make menu container hide when hovering all but two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm building a small "UberMenu" feature for my main menu, and it works almost as I want, except that I want the UberMenu container to hide if the mouse is not over either

1) the UberMenu button, or

2) the UberMenu container

Right now, if you hover over the UberMenu button, the container shows up, and if you enter the UberMenu container, and then proceed to hover over another menu item, it hides.

This is what I want, however if I hover the UberMenu button, **and then immediately** hover over another menu item, the container remains open.

I've tried over a dozen different snippets, but I haven't found a solution.

I guess I need some if / else statement added to the code?

Can someone give me some guidance here? Much appreciated! :-)

**This is the code I used:**

```
//When mouse hovers UberMenu button, Show Container
$(".uber-menu-test").hover(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); //To prevent default anchor tag behaviour
e.stopPropagation(); //To prevent parent container click event from firing

$(".uber-menu-frame").show(800);
});

// If mouse hovers either the content area or the navbararea, hide UberMenu    container again
$(".block-type-content, .navbararea").mouseenter(function() {
$(".uber-menu-frame").hide(800);

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events. On mouseenter show uber-menu-frame and on mouseleave hide uber-menu-frame.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps,

```
$(".uber-menu-test").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".uber-menu-frame").show(800);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".uber-menu-frame").hide(800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't allow me to enter the ubermenu container, because as soon as the mouse leaves the menu button, the container hides

Comment: I assume **class='block-type-content'** as your uber container. So apply the same mouseenter and mouseleave event to the above class also.

Add **stop()** to the mouseleave event callback, which helps you in avoiding looping of mouseenter and mouseleave events.


`$(".block-type-content").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".uber-menu-frame").show(800);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".uber-menu-frame").stop(true).hide(800);
});`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own by adding a timer, I'm not sure how solid this piece of code is, but it does the trick as far as I can tell!

For anyone interested:

```
$(".uber-menu-test").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To prevent default anchor tag behaviour
    e.stopPropagation(); //To prevent parent container click event from firing

    $(".uber-menu-frame").show(800);
});



var myTimer = false;

$(".uber-menu-test ,.uber-menu-frame").hover(function(){
    //mouse enter
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
},function(){
    //mouse leav
  myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
         $(".uber-menu-frame").fadeOut(800);
    },100)
});
```